# Seeking tutorials on raster data formats and raster manipulation?

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, references, image-mosaic, ecw

I am looking to improve my understanding of raster formats and how to manipulate them. I do not really want to go into the mathematics of it, but really want to know the differences between the different formats available, best practices, performance optimization etc.

Does anyone have any good sources which they would like to share?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the best *tutorials* I know about this matter are:

- the [**GDAL Raster Formats**](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html) about raster formats, where you can find a very exhaustive description of the most used raster formats, their creation option and various *hidden* properties;
- the [**GDAL utilities**](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_utilities.html) about raster manipulation.

These are a very good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Getting into Raster processing with GDAL is a very effective place to start and this tutorial on [Geoprocessing with Python using Open Source GIS](http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/) is great if a little old.  The first few lessons are on Vector data but you get to the Raster soon enough.

Also, reading the [ESRI documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_is_raster_data/009t00000002000000/) on raster data is very informative about processing methods and possible approaches often with examples.  The link will take you to the documentation pages and you can explore the wealth of information there (especially the pages on *how* a tool works).  Obviouslt tools will vary from GIS to GIS but they are often called similar things as they are mostly named by function.

Answer (score 1):

If you are up for some Esri training, they have a number of Virtual Campus courses available that deal with rasters. The search link is included below. Some you might start off with could be:

- Basics of Raster Data
- Displaying Raster Data Using ArcGIS
- Working With Rasters in ArcGIS Desktop

http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=search.results&searchterm=raster

Depending on your familiarity, there are also more advanced courses available too.

The ones I listed above are all pay courses. However, there are also a few webinars in the search results that are free and may be worth looking into as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wide field to investigate. A common understanding of the raster concept in GIS and areal imaging can be found at [CRISP](http://www.crisp.nus.edu.sg/~research/tutorial/image.htm). The  understanding of data formats is a more complex task. Some formats will be desinged or developed for certain purpose, like technical handling [of multiband satellite images](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2013/02/tip-open-bil-bip-and-bsq-files-in-qgis.html) or specialized storage of climate and weather modelling stuff [netcdf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetCDF) or [grib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRIB). Other data formats addressing portable image container formats with embbeded metadata and image lists like [TIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format) with GIS extentions like [GeoTiff](http://trac.osgeo.org/geotiff/). There are data formats which will be related to the advanced underling hard- or software (at the time) like [ECW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECW_%28file_format%29), [MrSID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MrSID), [SGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_Graphics_Image), [sun raster file](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=Sun_rasterfile) or [TGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truevision_TGA). At least you can find tutorials, how to deal with raster in an alogithmic way often subsumised under the buzzword "Computer Vision". [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) is one of the  popular open source libraries, which helps you to work raster stuff with good [tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html) and computer language backends like C++ and Python. For GIS related open source based format conversations and storage is GDAL (in [format description](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html) as well as in tutorial terms [WIKI](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/)/[API](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html)) a well documented library and toolkit.